# how to name page to access my taxonomy / terms

Tags: wordpress

I created my own customposttype

Stucture:
Album
-- Albumtypes (England,Island,France...)

In the Admin-Menu i can fill it nicely (the Items and populate the mainmenu).

but I get confused how to name my (Page / Template) to get access to this Items. Either I get directed to the Index-Page or I get the 404 Error.

the slug generated looks like this:

```
localhost/wp_v4/album/island/
localhost/wp_v4/album/england/
```

....

I tried naming my pages like:

```
page-album-england.php
page-album-template.php
taxonomy-album-england.php
taxonomy-album.php
```

what am I missing???

```
/*
    ==========================================
     Custom Post Type
    ==========================================
*/
function mkseventeen_custom_post_type (){

    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Album',
        'singular_name' => 'Album',
        'add_new' => 'Add Item',
        'all_items' => 'All Items',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Item',
        'new_item' => 'New Item',
        'view_item' => 'View Item',
        'search_item' => 'Search Album',
        'not_found' => 'No items found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No items found in trash',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Item'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        //'rewrite' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'album' ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'revisions',
        ),
        'taxonomies' => array('Albumtyp', 'post_tag'),  
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'exclude_from_search' => false
    );
    register_post_type('album',$args);
}
add_action('init','mkseventeen_custom_post_type');

function mkseventeen_custom_tayonomies(){
    // add new taxonomies hierarchical
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Albumtyp',  
        'singular_name' => 'Albumtyp',
        'search_items' => 'Search Albumtyp',
        'all_items' => 'All Albumtyps',   
        'parent_item' => 'Parent Albumtyp',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Albumtyp:',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Albumtyp',
        'update_item' => 'Update Albumtyp',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Work Albumtyp',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Albumtyp Name',
        'menu_name' => 'Albumtyp'
    );

    $args= array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'albumtyp')
    );
    register_taxonomy('Albumtyp', array('album'), $args);

}

add_action('init', 'mkseventeen_custom_tayonomies');
```

Comment: Have your re-visited and saved permalinks in the options/permalinks page?

Comment: yust did it twice - still not the effect desired...

Comment: Still also getting 404's? 404 should be an issue with the links itself. Not loading the correct template is because your naming isn't correct. it should be `taxonomy-albumtyp.php`(term archive), `category-album.php`(album archive) and `album.php`(single). See https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png

Comment: Also, in English it would be "Album type" unless that's not the word you're looking for.(if you fix the name of the type you also have to rename the template again)

Comment: thanks for your hint.. it is german :-)
but it does not work using taxonomy-albumtyp.php or taxonomy-albumtyp-england.php  and the others.   Is there perhaps something to do with the menu?

Comment: I stopped using the default Wordpress template hierarchy logic a long time ago so I might have picked the wrong one but all options are listed in the image. And I didn't think you meant German because all other words were in English (edit, new etc) ;-)

Comment: thanks anyway... I allways apprechiate help !!! -> and somehow you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works when I use:

single-album.php

addendum:

I remade exactly the same stucture with new names and suddenly the expected goal was achieved.

I renamed album to portfolio and the term from albumtype to klasse.
Now I have access to the post with:

> taxonomy-klasse.php

as described in the Codex.

Funny, but now it works...